# Meaning of this line of code in android given below...?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Class.forName(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 128).metaData.getString("com.sadaf.javafiles.MAIN_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME"))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is to create and add another activity to the top UI level

```
startActivity()
```

Can be called from any context/activity, mostly used like

```
finish()
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));
```

This is used to close the current activity and begin the next

For a more detailed explanation please refer to :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Class.forName(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 128).metaData.getString("com.sadaf.javafiles.MAIN_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME"))));
```

The intent requires a context and a class as parameter, the context is “this” (the current context from the activity that is currently being displayed)

The class is from Class.forName(String) which requires a String value to get the class name from an activity

It gets that String value from calling :

```
getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 128).metaData.getString(stringKey)
```

`stringKey` is the from the projects `AndroidManifest.xml` file android:name:

```
 <activity android:name="com.sadaf.javafiles.MAIN_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME" >
</activity>
```

So essentially what that piece of code is doing is getting the .class of your declared “main activity” programatically instead of using the “standard” way of just going MainActivity.class

Comment: Dear! But which activity

Comment: what does this mean? "MAIN_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME"